# Iterative list with "in range" function?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm still pretty new to this website and to python. So, please forgive my question possibly not being specific enough and the possibility of there already being an answer that I haven't found yet.

Basically, I am having trouble with for loops in python.

I want to create lists using the `in range()` function. Each successive list should set with the next number. For example

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5,6]
[3,4,5,6,7]
```

I want also the lists that are produced to be of equal length: for example, 5 numbers, 6 numbers or 7 numbers, etc.

```
l=[]
for i in range (1,10):
    for a in range (i):
        l.append (i)
        print (l[:5])

result is:

[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

and then it just repeats with 3. However, I want the next line two start with a new number, so 2 then the next line 3, etc.

I would greatly appreciate your help or at least a hint in the right direction ! 
If this question has already been answered, I would also appreciate having the link for the respective article.

Comment: u mean that tthe next list will be [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]? can u please give more examples

Comment: Hi! Do you need to hold on to them? Do you have to build them all with for loops? (eg is `for i in range(10): print(list(range(i, i + 5)))` what you want?)

Comment: No, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.


I want to have lists printed out on the screen in a successive, iterative order.
Like this:
[1,2,3,4,5],
[2,3,4,5,6],
[3,4,5 6,7],
[4,5,6,7,8],
So, all of the values in the next list are increased by one

Comment: @ChristopherChandler So is the code I gave OK?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty good. I don't think that I would have ever been able to fix that on my own. Is there any way to retrieve the values from the generated lists ?

Comment: Chris: For the record, Python has no `in range()` function. `in` is a keyword which could be followed by other iterable things, and `range()` is built-in class (which, like all classes, can be called like a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Christopher try this.

```
for i in range (0,4):
  l=[]
  for j in range (1+i,6+i):
    l.append (j)
  print(l)
```

Comment: This is a variant of what I had tried at the beginning (I didn't post the code here), but I couldn't get it to run properly. I really appreciate your help, Origin.

Answer (score 3):

Start over.  Code one or two lines at a time.  Print out variables to trace their values.  Do *not* write more code until you *know* that the current code does what you need.  A significant portion of your problem is that you tried to write too much code in one pass, more than you (yet) know how to handle.

Let's start here:

```
l=[]
for i in range (1,10):
    ...
```

Although you clearly state that you want a new starting point at each iteration, you initialize `l` only once.  This means that it will accumulate *all* of the values you append to it for the entire run of the program, rather than giving you a new list each time.

```
    for a in range (i):
```

How does this support anything that you're trying to do?  You will iterate once, then twice, then 3 times ... what part of your program is repeated in this fashion?  You clearly state that you want each list to be of the same length, but then you go out of your way to ensure that you accumulate an ever-increasing list on each completion of this inner loop.

---

Does this get you moving?

Comment: Hello Prune, 

thank you very for very detailed explanation.
Yeah, I noticed that It was trying to produce too much code at once and that it was basically being overwritten. 
I want to save the values as a list because I want to retrieve them using the splice function l:[5]. I want find the sum of the first three values of each list.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do probably looks something like this:

```
my_lists = []

for i in range(10):
    some_list = []
    for j in range(5):
        some_list.append(i + j)
    print(some_list)
    my_lists.append(some_list)

# or if you're being fancy,
# my_lists = [list(range(i, i + 5)) for i in range(10)]
```

I wouldn't worry too much about the ways to shorten and/or optimise the various
bits of it for now. This gives you a nice list `my_lists` of all the smaller
lists generated. Does that help you? I'd make sure you understand what's going
on in each loop, and why everything's structured the way it is.

(side note: the sum of the first three values of each list
 is given by a fairly straightforward arithmetic progression, so if you need to
 calculate it efficiently you'd be better off looking for an algebraic closed
 form.)

Comment: Yeah, this is also pretty good ! Thank you very much. This helps me out a lot and I can better understand the logic of the process :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this one:

```
def makelists(start, end, n):
    sequence = [i for i in range(start, end + 1)]
    if n == 1:
        print(sequence)
    else:
        print(sequence)
        for i in range(1, n):
            sequence = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, sequence))
            print(sequence)

makelists(1, 5, 3)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

For other inputs:

```
makelists(3, 10, 7)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```